# How to override setter method for property object that has own properties within?

Tags: objective-c, setter

I have an abstract class `AuthResult` that has property - `Token` model class.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Token;

@interface AuthResult : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;    // designated initializer

@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) Token *token; 
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL isAuthorized;

@end
```

`Token` model class, in his turn, has 5 properties within:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Token : NSObject

@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSString  *accessToken;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSDate    *expirationDate;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSString  *tokenType;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSString  *scope;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSString  *refreshToken;

@end
```

My goal is to override setter method in `AuthResult` class in order to handle different cases. E.g. after token refresh request it has `refreshToken` property empty so I do not need to erase it.

I tried this approach - setter in `AuthResult` class:

```
- (void)setToken:(Token *)token {
    _token.accessToken = token.accessToken;
    _token.expirationDate = token.expirationDate;
    _token.tokenType = token.tokenType;
    _token.scope = token.scope;

    if (token.refreshToken != nil) {
        // DO NOT OVERRIDE REFRESH_TOKEN HERE (after refresh token request it comes as null)
        _token.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It makes token object in `AuthResult` class always empty.

As I see - I don't have an access to object properties. I do have access to instance variable - "_token" object. But I do not have access to HIS properties.

Please advice. Thank you

Comment: i guess you should check for `_token == nil` before assigning the values and create it if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it doesn't work. It makes token object in AuthResult class always empty.

Your property `token` has a *reference type* and the default value for such is `nil`.

In the code you have supplied you never assign any value to `token` *itself*. For example the statement:

```
_token.accessToken = token.accessToken;
```

is an instruction to assign a value to the `accessToken` of the object *referenced by* the value in `_token` - but as the value in `_token` is never changed by you from `nil` there is no object referenced to change the property of. Due to the rules of Objective-C you don't get an error here, which some languages would give, the action simply does nothing.

The question is what are you really trying to do?

*If*, and I'm guessing at your intention here, your `AuthResult` object should have its own `Token` object, the properties of which should be modified by your setter then you are almost there, you just need to allocate a `Token` object for your `AuthResult` to own. You could do this with code like:

```
- (void)setToken:(Token *)token
{
   if(_token == nil)
      _token = Token.new; // don't have a token yet, allocate one
   // now update the fields of our _token from token
   _token.accessToken = token.accessToken;
   _token.expirationDate = token.expirationDate;
   ...
```

While that solves your immediate problem it does not address the large design issue, should you be doing this? The value in `_token` can be read by the getter, and as it is a reference that means its properties can be changed by someone using the getter and then setting them. If the object reference by `_token` is meant to belong to your `AuthResult` instance that maybe not what you want, for example you might want the getter to return a *copy*.

So think about your model.

HTH

Comment: if  I understood correctly I should use this structure to return a copy of my token object in getter? - `return [_token copy];`

Comment: @BogdanLaukhin - Yes, *if* you want to return a copy that is how you can do it (provided `Token` implements `NSCopying` of course).

Comment: thanks a lot - initialising a token object - solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the token object.
You can do it like this:

```
- (void)setToken:(Token *)token {
_token = [Token new]; //initialize Token Object
_token.accessToken = token.accessToken;
_token.expirationDate = token.expirationDate;
_token.tokenType = token.tokenType;
_token.scope = token.scope;

if (token.refreshToken != nil) {
    // DO NOT OVERRIDE REFRESH_TOKEN HERE (after refresh token request it comes as null)
    _token.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
}
}
```